# What is the best web application where native French speakers will correct French phrases/texts?

Tags: webapp-rec

**Does anyone know of a social website where native French language speakers will correct phrases or texts for free?**, i.e. for reputation points and badges etc. like at StackExchange?

For example, as I learn French I collect phrases. For many of these I simply got the translations from **Google translate**, so I would like to have a **native French speaker** look at these and **respond with corrections** to these translations according to what a native speaker would expect and not what Google Translate would generate:

```
20. You said "_____". What does that mean?
20. Tu as dit "_____". Qu'est-ce que cela signifie?

21. Tell me if I'm pronouncing this phrase correctly:
21. Dit-moi si je suis prononçant cette phrase bien:

22. How do you say "_____" in French?
22. Comment dit-on "_____" en français?

23. What is this? What is this called?
23. Qu'est ce que c'est? Qu'est-ce que ça s'appelle?

24. Could you write down that phrase for me?
24. Pourrais-tu écrire cette phrase pour moi?

25. How do you pronounce this word? (pointing to a word)
25. Comment peut-on prononcer ce mot?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a site [lang-8.com](http://lang-8.com/) (that's "lang-infinity" apparently, rather than "lang-eight") which might suit you, as well as [italki.com](http://www.italki.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can take  a look at [livemocha.com](http://www.livemocha.com/)

You can learn any language and have your exercises corrected by native speakers.

Comment: yes, I looked at that but it seems you can only post on certain topics (e.g. "describe 6 objects you see" or "describe your country and city") and the text is limited to 1024 characters, or is there something I'm missing about the service?

Comment: Yes, you have to do certain excercises in a certain order, and native speakers correct them. As far as I'm aware, you can't just upload arbitrary text and have it corrected...

Answer (score 0):

There was a proposition made on Area51 about making a site for this :

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1979/english-french-translation

If you participate a lot, it might open one day.